# Does the improper integral exist?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to find a continuous and bounded function $\mathrm{f}(x)$ such that the limit
$$ \lim_{T\to\infty}  \frac{1}{T}\, \int_0^T \mathrm{f}(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$ 
doesn't exist.

I thought about $\mathrm{f}(x) = \sin x$ but I am not sure if the fact that we divide by $T$ may some how make it converge to zero.

What do you think ?

Comment: "such that the limit" what? exists? does not exist?

Comment: $sin(x)$ does not work since the antiderivative $-cos(x)$ is also bounded for all $T$. Hence the limit is zero...

Comment: Such a function exists, but is a pain (for me) to write down. Basically the function can be +1 so that the integral hits ${1 \over 2}$ then transition to -1 so that the integral hits $-{1 \over 2} $, etc, etc.

Answer (score 6):

$ \sin(x) $ won't do, but it's only a tad trickier.
$$ f(x) = \sin\left(\ln(x)\right) $$ should do the job (you can integrate it exactly by elementary techniques and then show it is $ \mathcal{O}(T) $).

Note that the function is bounded and continuous in $ (0,+\infty) $.

Comment: $\int_0^T f(x)dx=-1/2T(cos(ln(T))-sin(ln(T)))$... divide that by $T$ and you get $-1/2(cos(ln(T))-sin(ln(T)))\rightarrow -1$ hence the limit exists for this $f(x)$. Maybe I missed something...

Comment: @Thorben: As $T \to \infty$, that oscillates between $\pm {1 \over 2 \sqrt{2}}$. I think this is a nice solution.

Comment: This only needs a minor tweak to make $f$ be continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat you are absolutly right! As I look again at the function I have no idea how I obtained this limit... sorry for that!

Comment: @Thorben: No problem, I wouldn't have caught it if not for symbolic integration...

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't think $ f $ ought to be continuous at 0, since integrating in $ (0,+\infty) $ only requires integrability (say, continuity) in the open set. However, if one were to require continuity at 0, he/she could just define $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin\left(\ln(x)\right) \quad &\mathrm{if}\,x\ge 1\\0\quad&\mathrm{if}\,0\le x\le 1\end{cases}, $$ which is indeed continuous and bounded on $ [0,+\infty) $. :)

Comment: The behaviour at $t=0$ doesn't matter as you observe, I was really just pointing out that it can be easily modified to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ without affecting the result. (Nice answer.)

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is simple, but the details laborious. Keep the function at $+1$ long enough so the average hits some positive value, then keep the function at 
$-1$ long enough so the average hits some negative value and repeat.

Let $t_n = 2^{n+2}-4$.
Let $f_n(t) = \begin{cases} t-t_n, & t \in [t_n,t_n+1] \\
1 , & t \in (t_n+1,t_{n+1}-1) \\
1-(t-(t_{n+1}-1)) , & t \in [t_{n+1}+1, t_n] \\
0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Note that $f_n$ has support $(t_n,t_{n+1})$,
and $\int_0^{t_{n+1}} f_n = t_n+3$.

Let $\phi(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kf_k(t)$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{t_{n+1}} \phi_n &=&
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (t_k+3) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (2^{k+2}-1) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^{k+2}- \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k  \\
&=& {4 \over 3} (1-(-2)^{n+1})- {1 \over  2} (1 - (-1)^{n+1})
\end{eqnarray}
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma_n &=&  {1 \over t_{n+1} }\int_0^{t_{n+1}} \phi_n \\
&=& {4 \over 3} {  (1-(-2)^{n+1})- {1 \over  2} (1 - (-1)^{n+1}) \over 2^{n+3}-4} \\
&=& {1 \over 3}{  (1-(-2)^{n+1})- {1 \over  2} (1 - (-1)^{n+1}) \over 2^{n+1}-1} \\
&=& {1 \over 3} { {1 \over 2^{n+1} } - (-1)^{n+1} - {1 \over 2^{n+2} (1 - (-1)^{n+1} }\over 1 - {1 \over 2^{n+1} } }
\end{eqnarray}
We see that $\liminf_n \sigma_n = - {1 \over 3}$, $\limsup_n \sigma_n = {1 \over 3}$, hence the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The integral has to diverge to infinity if this limit is to not exist, (of course any other limit will give zero overall). Given the type $``\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}"$ limit, if we apply L'Hopitals; $$\displaystyle\lim_{T\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{T}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\ dx = \lim_{T\to \infty} f(T)$$

This makes it clear that the limit doesn't exist iff $f$ is not bounded, so there is no suitable function.

Comment: If the function has a limit as $t \to \infty$ this is true, but it doesn't have to have such a limit. It is straightforward, if tedious, to create a bounded $f$ that doesn't have an average limit.

Comment: "The integral has to diverge to infinity if this limit is to not exist". Nope. "does not converge " is not synonymous to "diverges to infinity".

Answer (score 0):

What about $\mathrm{f}(x)=T$?

$$ \lim_{T\to\infty}  \frac{1}{T}\, \int_0^T \mathrm{f}(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{T\to\infty}  \frac{1}{T}\, \int_0^T T~\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{T\to\infty}  \frac{1}{T}\, T^2=\infty$$

Comment: What does this mean? $T$ is not a constant.

Comment: $T$ does not depend on $x$. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This is genius!! So simple and brilliant.

Comment: @copper.hat: See `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+1%2FT+*+%28integral+from+0+to+T+of+T+with+respect+to+x%29+as+T+-%3E+inf&a=*C.T-_*Variable-&a=UnitClash_*T.*Teslas.dflt--`

Comment: If $T$ does not depend on $x$, then $f$ is constant. If $f$ is constant the integral evaluates to the same constant.

Comment: @rubik: What am I supposed to see there?

Comment: @copper.hat: Exactly. Then $\int_{0}^{T} f(x) dx = \left [ Tx \right ]_{0}^{T} = T^2 - 0 = T^2$. Then the limit is as zighalo wrote.

Comment: Ahhh I know where we went wrong. This limit is $\infty$ but the question said that the limit should not exist. So This is not the correct answer I believe. The rest was right, however.

Comment: @rubik: If $f(x) = T$, then $f$ has the constant value $T$. We can write $\int_0^T f(x) dx = f(0)T$. Here I am using $f(0)$ to avoid the confusion with the symbol $T$ used in the limits of the integral. Then when you divide by $T$ you get $f(0)$. This is not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @copper.hat: I now agree that this is not what the OP was looking for, but the steps are indeed correct. The limit evaluates to $\infty$.

Comment: @rubik: It depends on which limit you mean. You cannot replace $f(x)$ by $T$ in the context above.

Comment: When we say that the limit does not exist? If the limit is $\infty$

Comment: What you have written above makes no sense. When you write $f(x) = T$, then $f$ is a constant. So, the integral should read ${1 \over S} \int_0^S f(x) dx = {1 \over S} \int_0^S T dx = {S T \over S} = T$, which is a constant. You cannot have $f$ be both constant and non-constant.

Comment: Yes $f$ is constant. Really I do not get what you are trying to say.

Comment: When you integrate $f$ above, you are integrating the function $x \mapsto x$, which is different to the function $x \mapsto T$. You are confusing the integration variable $T$ with the value you have assigned to $f$ (a different $T$).

Comment: @zighalo:  $f(x)$ is taken to be defined prior to the creation of the expression containing the limit which binds the formal parameter $T$.  At the earlier time, $T$ is a free variable.  At the later time, the formal parameter of the limit must be unbound in its context, so cannot be any symbol already in the context.  If you set $f(x)=T$, then $T$ cannot be the formal parameter in the limit; it must be some other free-at-that-time variable.